# Add missing date index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have loaded a CSV files with index datetime which is the last day of months in a year. I wanted to fill missing dates with empty values as rows.

Following is my CSV file structure

```
Date    Australia   China
2011-01-31  4.75    5.81
2011-02-28  4.75    5.81
2011-03-31  4.75    6.06
2011-04-30  4.75    6.06
```

I want to fill all the dates in a month with empty columns.

I tried the following code but it is not working.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col="Date")
df.reindex(pd.date_range("2011-01-01", "2011-10-31"), fill_value="NaN")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to set the `DatetimeIndex` on your dataframe, so I would modify your code into:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col="Date")
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range("2011-01-01", "2011-10-31"), fill_value="NaN")
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

This should work.

EDIT: add sample test output:

```
...
2011-01-24,NaN,NaN
2011-01-25,NaN,NaN
2011-01-26,NaN,NaN
2011-01-27,NaN,NaN
2011-01-28,NaN,NaN
2011-01-29,NaN,NaN
2011-01-30,NaN,NaN
2011-01-31,4.75,5.81
2011-02-01,NaN,NaN
2011-02-02,NaN,NaN
2011-02-03,NaN,NaN
2011-02-04,NaN,NaN
2011-02-05,NaN,NaN
2011-02-06,NaN,NaN
...
```

Comment: @Unnikrishnan you're welcome, please consider upvoting the answer if it worked well for your purposes.

Comment: Always nice when one additional line solves the problem.

Comment: use `np.nan`, my next step was `df.interpolate()` and this caused me a lot of confusion as my output *appeared* to line up with the docs