# Adding missing dates in csv file having duplicate dates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset which has 134 columns and 11961 rows. It has duplicates dates as the event took for 2 days. So it has been recorded as three different rows.
So when i tried to add the missing dates with the help of this link, [Add missing date index in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691812/add-missing-date-index-in-dataframe/34692354). But i was getting an error.

```
File "C:\Users\kumar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3576, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

The original data is

```
    date  provstate  city  latitude  longitude
    1979-8-26   13  1850    22.804567   86.202875
    1979-8-27   7   3312    28.585836   77.153336
    1979-8-27   7   3312    28.585836   77.153336
    1979-8-29   13  1850    22.804567   86.202875
```

the code i used is this

```
    df = pd.read_csv("G:\\Required\\Internship\\Fresh\\temp.csv", index_col='date')
    df.head()
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
    df = df.reindex(pd.date_range("1979-01-01", "2017-12-31"), fill_value=0)
    df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

I expect the output to be

```
    date    provstate   city    latitude    longitude
    1979-8-26   13  1850    22.804567   86.202875
    1979-8-27   7   3312    28.585836   77.153336
    1979-8-27   7   3312    28.585836   77.153336
    1979-8-28   0   0       0           0
    1979-8-29   13  1850    22.804567   86.202875
```

But actually im getting the error

```
File "C:\Users\kumar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3576, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the duplicates, like `1979-8-27` row? Or can we remove duplicates?

Comment: I want the duplicates to be present. But also show how to remove duplicates

Comment: Did you even look at my answer? It provides both..

Comment: I verified now.... 
Its working...
Thanks a lot

Actually i got error. But then i forgot something to write. Now it works perfectly

Comment: Sir, what should i do to delete duplicate rows and merge the duplicate data with the single row(the unique row)

Comment: Method 1 does that exactly? Method 2 keeps the duplicate rows. If you're question was not asked properly, submit a new question and try to explain correctly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1: Using `resample`

*note: this drops the duplicate rows*

```
df.resample('D').first().fillna(0)

            provstate    city   latitude  longitude
date                                               
1979-08-26       13.0  1850.0  22.804567  86.202875
1979-08-27        7.0  3312.0  28.585836  77.153336
1979-08-28        0.0     0.0   0.000000   0.000000
1979-08-29       13.0  1850.0  22.804567  86.202875
```

---

#### Method 2: Using `pd.concat`, `boolean indexing` & `resample`

```
d = df.resample('D').first().fillna(0)

df = pd.concat([df, d[~d.index.isin(df.index)]]).sort_index()

            provstate    city   latitude  longitude
date                                               
1979-08-26       13.0  1850.0  22.804567  86.202875
1979-08-27        7.0  3312.0  28.585836  77.153336
1979-08-27        7.0  3312.0  28.585836  77.153336
1979-08-28        0.0     0.0   0.000000   0.000000
1979-08-29       13.0  1850.0  22.804567  86.202875
```